# Proving closed immersions are affine

Tags: algebraic-geometry

I'd like to prove that closed immersions are affine.

The definition of closed immersion I use is the following: a morphism $f:X\rightarrow Y$ is a closed immersion if $f$ induces a homeomorphism of $X$ over a closed subset of $Y$ and $f^{\#}:O_Y\rightarrow f_*O_X$ is surjective.
I also use the following notation: if $X$ is a scheme and $s\in\Gamma(X,O_X)$ then $X_s$ denotes the set of points $P\in X$ such that $s_P$ is invertible in $O_{X,P}.$
And I also have the following characterization of affine schemes: if $X$ can be covered by finitely many subsets $X_s$ and each one of these $X_s$ is affine then $X$ is affine.

I think my answer is wrong because I don't use the fact that $f^{\#}$ is surjective but I don't see where my mistake lies, I would be grateful if anyone could tell me what it is (or confirm that my proof is correct, which I think is unlikely):
Let $f:X\rightarrow Y$ be a closed immersion, $Z=f(X)$ and $U=\operatorname{Spec} A$ an affine open subset of $Y$. By considering the induced morphism $f^{-1}(U)\rightarrow U$ we can suppose that $U=Y.$ Every point $x\in X$ has an affine open neighborhood $U_x$ and $f(U_x)$ is an open subset of the closed subset $Z$ so there exists an open subset $V_x\subset Y$ such that $f(U_x)=Z\cap V_x.$ Let $D(g_x)$ be a basic open subset containing $f(x).$ Then $f^{-1}(D(g_x))=X_{h_x}$ where $h_x=f^{\#}(g_x)\in \Gamma(X,O_X).$ And each $X_{h_x}$ is affine since $X_{h_x}=X_{h_x}\cap U_x=D(k_x)$ where $U_x=\operatorname{Spec} B$ and $k_x=h_{x|U_x}\in B$ is the restriction of $h_x$ to $U_x.$ Now since $Y$ is quasi-compact $Z$ can be covered by finitely many subsets $D(g_x)$ and so $X$ can be covered by finitely many subsets $X_{h_x}$ each one of which is affine and so $X$ is affine.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Small quibble: in your characterization of affineness you want $s$ to live in $\Gamma (X, O_X)$, right? Not some stalk $O_x$.

Comment: @TabesBridges yes $s$ has to belong to $\Gamma(X,O_X)$

Comment: OK, I have edited your question to reflect that.

Answer (score 0):

You probably already know the answer as the question is quite old but for the sake of completness I'll write something short. As far as I can tell your proof is correct. The assumption that $f$ is a homeomorphism onto a closed subset of $Y$ is strong enough to prove that $f$ is affine and it is no problem that you didn't use that $f^\sharp$ is surjective! (for a reference check this stacks project lemma: https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/04DE)